# setFirstResult/setMaxResults generates wrong SQL for PostgreSQL since upgrading to Hibernate 6

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, offset

We are updating the legacy application from Java 8 to Java 17 with Jakarta and the hibernate lib with postgresql. Now we have updated the with

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>
            org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Existing code where we are using pagination logic it causing issue with query formation

```
protected void setPagination(int start, int count, TypedQuery<?> query) {
  // Pagination if desired.
  if (start != 0 || count != 0) {
    if (start >= 1) {
      start = (start - 1) * count;
    } else {
      start = start * count;
    }
    **query.setFirstResult(start);
    query.setMaxResults(count);**
  }
}
```

after execution of code and getResultLIst() we are getting the below error with query.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [

order by 2 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only] 
[ERROR: syntax error at or near "rows" Position: 967] [n/a]
```

If we execute the query without this code of block we are getting the result.

Comment: Apparently you forgot to upgrade the PostgreSQL DB as well. See the answers of the abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: Am using the latest maven dependency for PostgreSQL. 42.7.1

Comment: The physical PostgreSQL DB itself. That Maven dependency represents the JDBC driver not the DB.